# Find range of values in each unique day

Tags: r, range

I have the following example:

```
Date1 <- seq(from = as.POSIXct("2010-05-01 02:00"), 
             to = as.POSIXct("2010-10-10 22:00"), by = 3600)
Dat <- data.frame(DateTime = Date1,
                  t = rnorm(length(Date1)))
```

I would like to find the range of values in a given day (i.e. maximum - minimum).

First, I've defined additional columns which define the unique days in terms of the date and in terms of the day of year (doy).

```
Dat$date <- format(Dat$DateTime, format = "%Y-%m-%d") # find the unique days
Dat$doy <- as.numeric(format(Dat$DateTime, format="%j")) # find the unique days
```

To then find the range I tried

```
by(Dat$t, Dat$doy, function(x) range(x))
```

but this returns the range as two values not a single value, So, my question is, how do I find the calculated range for each day and return them in a data.frame which has

```
new_data <- data.frame(date = unique(Dat$date),
                       range = ...)
```

Can anyone suggest a method for doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to use `tapply` for this kind of thing. `ave` is also useful sometimes. Here:

```
> dr = tapply(Dat$t,Dat$doy,function(x){diff(range(x))})
```

Always check tricksy stuff:

```
> dr[1]
     121 
3.084317 
> diff(range(Dat$t[Dat$doy==121]))
[1] 3.084317
```

Use the names attribute to get the day-of-year and the values to make a data frame:

```
> new_data = data.frame(date=names(dr),range=dr)
> head(new_data)
    date    range
121  121 3.084317
122  122 4.204053
```

Did you want to convert the number day-of-year back to a date object?

Comment: great. I can use the Dat$date in the OP to convert back to date. Thanks

Comment: how do you do this if you want to find the range based on multiple criteria (e.g., perhaps pairwise combos of date of year and time of day)?

Answer (score 2):

```
# Use the data.table package
require(data.table)

# Set seed so data is reproducible 
set.seed(42)

# Create data.table
Date1 <- seq(from = as.POSIXct("2010-05-01 02:00"), to = as.POSIXct("2010-10-10 22:00"), by = 3600)
DT <- data.table(date = as.IDate(Date1), t = rnorm(length(Date1)))

# Set key on data.table so that it is sorted by date
setkey(DT, "date")

# Make a new data.table with the required information (can be used as a data.frame)
new_data <- DT[, diff(range(t)), by = date]

#            date       V1
# 1:   2010-05-01 4.943101
# 2:   2010-05-02 4.309401
# 3:   2010-05-03 4.568818
# 4:   2010-05-04 2.707036
# 5:   2010-05-05 4.362990
# ---                    
# 159: 2010-10-06 2.659115
# 160: 2010-10-07 5.820803
# 161: 2010-10-08 4.516654
# 162: 2010-10-09 4.010017
# 163: 2010-10-10 3.311408
```